# Can't get Thread.interrupt to work

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, interrupt-handling

I have a program that performs some file I/O and then sleeps for a few seconds, checks if the files have changed, then sleeps if they're the same. If they've changed, it performs the same file I/O then goes back to sleep. I want to implement a keystroke that will wake this thread if pressed but I can't get the thread to process the InterruptedException. My (simplified) code is here:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class StackOverFlowExample extends JFrame{

    private class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {
        boolean keyEventDone = false;

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED){
                if((e.getKeyCode() == 80 && e.getModifiers() == 11) && !keyEventDone){
                    System.out.println("interrupting");
                    interrupt();
                }
            }
            if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == 80){
                    keyEventDone = false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

public void interrupt(){
    System.out.println("recieved interrupt");
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String fileName = "file Name";
    String oldFileName = "oldFileName";
    JFrame frame = new StackOverFlowExample();
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(217, 104);

    do{
        if(!fileName.equals(oldFileName)){

        }else{
            try {
                System.out.println("Same file");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("continuing");
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    System.out.println("continuing");
                    continue;
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        oldFileName = fileName;
    }while(true);

}
public StackOverFlowExample(){
    super("");
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    setContentPane(pane);
    KeyboardFocusManager manager = 
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new MyDispatcher());
}

}
```

There's other stuff in the class but none of it has to do with threads or anything. Also, I know checking file name isn't the best way to do this, but in my application the file name will always be different if the file is different because the file name is generated based on time.

When I press "ctrl+shift+alt+p" to wake the thread it prints out "interrupting" from the MyDispatcher class and "recieved interrupt" from the interrupt method of the main class, but nothing else and the thread just keeps sleeping

All of the examples I've seen of interrupting sleeping threads have the threads not in the main class. Is this the reason why mine doesn't work?

Comment: Since you've omitted all the important details such as how you start the thread (there is more than one thread, right?) it's going to be impossible to help you.  Please reduce this down to a [mcve].

Comment: This is the only thread! Please don't downvote me if you can't read my question. I state EXPLICITLY: "There's other stuff in the class but NONE OF IT HAS TO DO WITH THREADS or anything." Can you please remove your downvote so you don't remove my ability to ask questions in the future.

Comment: You appear to be interrupting the wrong Thread. But it's not **only** a Thread. Without a decent MCVE you hamstring our ability to fully understand your code.

Comment: And we don't want to see the other things. Please read the rationale and description behind the [mcve] protocol, and please do create one. But again, you appear to be interrupting the Swng EDT thread while the while true loop is being run on the main thread. Do you test what thread is what?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am not sure what you mean by MCVE. How would I go about interrupting the thread that gets put to sleep in my main method?

Comment: @joshua0823: Jim gave you the MCVE link!

Comment: And how to interrupt that thread -- hard to say without code that we can compile, run test and modify. I wouldn't do any of this in the main thread if it were my code. Myself I'd use a SwingWorker.

Comment: A downvote means that the question does not fit the guidelines for this site.  If you want help you should make a [mcve].  However, the fact that there's only one thread, the main thread, means you have a serious misunderstanding.  Using `thread.interrupt()` is meaningless in a single-thread application.

Comment: @JimGarrison: it's not single threaded, but he may not know or understand this, since listener code would likely be run on the EDT. This can be tested using the `SwingUtilties.isEventDispatchThread()` method, or by testing the `hashCode()` or id via `getId()` of the threads.

Comment: You're probably right, but without the context it's hard to tell.

Comment: I'll remove my down-vote for now, but hope to see your MCVE program soon.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  MCVE was added

Comment: @JimGarrison How could I change this so it will check every 10 seconds but I can make it execute by keycode as well? I need a Timer don't I?

Comment: Print out thread ID's -- as I suspected, they're separate threads.

Comment: in `interrupt()` method, place `System.out.println("interrupt Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());` and equivalent in the do-while loop (different println's). Or test if it is event dispatch, same result. You're interrupting the wrong thread.

Comment: @JimGarrison: he actually *did* create a valid MCVE on short notice. Kudos to him, and a rare and pleasant occurrence.

Comment: Downvote converted to upvote, thank you @joshua0823, good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, you're interrupting the wrong thread, and will want to pass the correct one in. For example, taking your code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StackOverFlowExample extends JFrame {
    static String oldFileName = "oldFileName";
    private Thread runningThread;

    private class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {
        boolean keyEventDone = false;

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                if ((e.getKeyCode() == 80 && e.getModifiers() == 11) && !keyEventDone) {
                    System.out.println("interrupting");
                    interrupt();
                }
            }
            if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == 80) {
                    keyEventDone = false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    // pass in the correct thread to interrupt
    public void setRunningThread(Thread runningThread) {
        this.runningThread = runningThread;
    }

    public void interrupt() {
        System.out.println("recieved interrupt");
        // !! Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        runningThread.interrupt();
        System.out.println("interrupt Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            String fileName = "file Name";
            StackOverFlowExample frame = new StackOverFlowExample();
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(217, 104);

            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                do {
                    if (!fileName.equals(oldFileName)) {

                    } else {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("do-while Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                            System.out.println("Same file");
                            Thread.sleep(10000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            System.out.println("continuing");
                            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                                System.out.println("continuing");
                                continue;
                            }
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    oldFileName = fileName;
                } while (true);
            });

            // pass in the thread
            frame.setRunningThread(thread);
            thread.start(); // start it running
        });
    }

    public StackOverFlowExample() {
        super("");
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        setContentPane(pane);
        KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new MyDispatcher());
    }

}
```

---

---

You know, perhaps a simpler way to do what you're trying to do:

- Create a Swing Timer that repeats every x seconds (we'll use 10 sec in this example)
- Inside the timer start a new Thread, perhaps a SwingWorker if we need it to interact more directly with the GUI, that checks the file situation and does file I/O if needed.
- Give the timer an initial delay of 0, so it starts *or restarts* immediately
- Use Key Bindings instead of the fidgety KeyListener
- In the Action that is triggered by our binding, simply call `restart()` on the Swing Timer which restarts its actions now immediately since the initial delay was 0, and then restarts the 10 second wait.

Something like:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StackOverflowExample2 extends JPanel {
    // 10 seconds between tasks
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 10 * 1000;
    int keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_P;
    int modifiers = InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK | InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK
            | InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK;
    private KeyStroke shftCtrlAltP = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, modifiers);
    private int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
    private InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
    private ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
    private Timer myTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());

    public StackOverflowExample2() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        // create key binding
        inputMap.put(shftCtrlAltP, shftCtrlAltP.toString());
        actionMap.put(shftCtrlAltP.toString(), new MyAction());
        // myWorker.execute();
        myTimer.setInitialDelay(0);
        myTimer.start();
    }

    private class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Key pressed");
            myTimer.restart(); // simply re-start the timer
        }
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // launch SwingWorker or other thread to check if files have changed
            // and if so do file I/O
            System.out.println("Timer running");
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        StackOverflowExample2 mainPanel = new StackOverflowExample2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("StackOverflowExample2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Also, your code and program design currently calls for *polling* the state of a file or multiple files and then performing some action if they change. A more efficient alternative is to not poll at all but instead use the [Java NIO WatchService API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html), part of the core Java API since Java 7.

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: @joshua0823: please see edit to answer for a possibly simpler solution

Comment: I like the WatchService solution. I think I'll switch to that since I don't really like the whole waiting and then checking thing